# Show only selected parameter and hide un-selected ones in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

How do I write an expression in SSRS that shows only selected parameters when the report is run or previewed?
Thank you.

Comment: i can't understand you could you explain better your question

Comment: I want that when a report is run, only selected parameters are displayed. For example, I have up to 6 parameters in a report and all allow null values. A user can input any parameter of choice. Now assuming that a user inputted or selected only parameters, I want to write an expression that allows them to see only the list or names of the selected parameters in the Header or Footer body of the report rather than seeing all parameters returned.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can show that list in Header or Footer but you can hide your parameters using this lines in the code behind

> ```
>   Rpt.ShowParameterPrompts = False
>     Rpt.ShowCredentialPrompts = False
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to hide the parameters from user but that only what they selected are shown in Report Header of Footer through expression. I am asking how that could be written in my expression to only show or let users see what they selected at the report Header or Footer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In your expression you can use: "Parameters!.Value" to reference the value of a parameter; so to put that value into, say, a basic text box control, you can simply set the expression to:

```
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value
```

It gets trickier with multivalued parameters.  To reference the first value in the collection, you'd write:

```
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value(0)
```

And you can replace 0 with the position of any value in the array that you'd prefer.  Of course, obviously it's impractical to write:

```
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value(0)
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value(1)
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value(2)
...
=Parameters!<parameter name>.Value(9999)
```

For every potential parameter you have.  Instead, you can use the "JOIN" function, specifying the delimiter you'd like, and it will return all of your parameters wrapped up into a single string:

```
=Join(Parameters!<parameter name>.Value, ",")
```

See this page for more info on working with multivalued parameters:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264.aspx